# Qlikview generate qvd by month

Tags: sql, qlikview, qliksense

i've join two table with left join and will generate the qvd. I would like to generate the qvd based on the month of the date. For example if there are 12 dates from jan to dec, then there will be 12 qvd files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look through all values in the `Month` field. Each iteration will load data from 
`TEMP_TABLE1` for one month and store this temp table into a qvd file.

The script below can give you an idea how this can be achieved

```
// Load some data
RandData:
Load 
  *
Inline [
Value , Month
1     , Jan
2     , Feb
3     , Mar
4     , Apr
5     , May
6     , Jun
7     , Jul
8     , Aug
9     , Sep
10    , Oct
11    , Nov
12    , Dec
];

// Start looping through each distinct value in the Month field
for i = 1 to FieldValueCount('Month')
    // In-loop variable that will get the current increment value from the Month field
    let sMonhValue = FieldValue('Month', $(i));
    trace Storing data for Month --> $(sMonhValue);

    // NoConcatenate is used to tell Qlik to not concatenate the same tables
    NoConcatenate

    // Load the data for the current iteration month from the main data table
    TempTable:
    Load
      *
    Resident
      RandData
    where
      Month = $(i)
    ;

    // Store one month data in qvd. The name of the qvd will include the month value        
    Store TempTable into RandData_$(sMonhValue).qvd;

    // The Store statement above will store the qvd files next to the qvw file. 
    // If the qvd files need to be stored somewhere else - just provide the path like:
    //Store TempTable into c:\users\UserName\Documents\RandData_$(sMonhValue).qvd;

    // Drop the temp table. Otherwise it will get concatenated to the "previos" temp table 
    Drop Table TempTable;
next

// At the end the app will contain only one table - `RandData`
```

Comment: hi, the code did create 12 qvd but only the first qvd have data while the rest don't have any data. My i don't have month field. Only arrive dt where the format is like 05=06=18 0 - June and 05-07-18 - July.

Comment: hi i added this  MonthName("ARRIVE_DT") as MONTH_NAME, //find out the monthname present in the data to use the month name in arrive dt..and the qvd from june to sept is generated but no data in all of the qvd

Comment: cab refer to my new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162398/qlikview-no-data-generated

Comment: Just run the qvw with the codes you provided and it return empty values as well. Can have one sample with data generated for all months? thanks